# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’

Tags: image, makefile, build, buildroot

I am trying to build an image for the imx6QPsabre board with Buildroot.
The make process starts well but it stops and I get this error messages (down) on my terminal.
Does anyone knows how to solve this?
Thank you,
regards

```
m@LAPTOP-TTGEKDO8:~/buildroot$ sudo make
[sudo] password for m:
>>> host-util-linux 2.37.2 Building
PATH="/home/m/buildroot/output/host/bin:/home/m/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin" PKG_CONFIG="/home/m/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config" PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="/" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="/home/m/buildroot/output/host/lib/pkgconfig:/home/m/buildroot/output/host/share/pkgconfig"  /usr/bin/make -j9  -C /home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2/
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2'
/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2'
Making all in po
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2/po'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2/po'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2'
  CC       sys-utils/dmesg-dmesg.o
  CC       lib/dmesg-monotonic.o
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-blkdev.lo
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-buffer.lo
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-canonicalize.lo
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-color-names.lo
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-crc32.lo
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-crc32c.lo
make[3]: *** [Makefile:11275: sys-utils/dmesg-dmesg.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
  CC       lib/libcommon_la-encode.lo
make[3]: *** [Makefile:11289: lib/dmesg-monotonic.o] Error 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10197: lib/libcommon_la-color-names.lo] Error 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10204: lib/libcommon_la-crc32.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10218: lib/libcommon_la-encode.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10183: lib/libcommon_la-buffer.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10211: lib/libcommon_la-crc32c.lo] Error 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10176: lib/libcommon_la-blkdev.lo] Error 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Waddress-of-packed-member’
make[3]: *** [Makefile:10190: lib/libcommon_la-canonicalize.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:14611: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:6321: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2'
make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:294: /home/m/buildroot/output/build/host-util-linux-2.37.2/.stamp_built] Error 2
```

Comment: That option was added in GCC 9.1.  If the version of GCC you have is older than that, then you'll get this message since your version of GCC is too old to recognize it.  You don't say what version of GCC you have but apparently this software wants a newer version.

Comment: Now I want to build an image from the next files:

Comment: imx6qp-sabresd.dtb
rootfs.ext2
rootfs.ext4 -> rootfs.ext2
rootfs.tar
sdcard.img
sdimage.img
boot.bin
u-boot.img
u-boot.imx
zImage

do zou have a suggestion how to do that?

Comment: If you have further but different issues, you should post it as a different question. You are more likely to find help there.